# How to fix: fomat date inside myaccount/order.php page

Tags: php, date, woocommerce, format

On `myaccount>order` page the date format printed is m/d/Y, and need to change to d/m/Y.

On `wordpress>configuration>date` format i already put `"d/m/Y/`. I found on `woocommerce/myaccount/orders.php` this code:

```
    <?php echo esc_html( wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ); ?>
```

I tried to change to:

```
 <?php echo esc_html( wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created()->format('d/m/Y') ) ); ?>
```

But didn't work well, i dont know why on orders page woocommerce doesn't follow the WordPress date.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the date to RFC3339, which is a predefined format.

```
$inputDate = "2014-03-10 05:40:00";
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat(DATE_RFC3339, $inputDate);
echo $datetime->format(DateTime::RFC3339);
```

Seems like you'll want to use the `$order->get_date_created()` as the `$inputDate` to get where you're goin.

---

Alternatively, you can also simply

```
date("c", strtotime($order->get_date_created()))
```

which should get you what you're after as well.

---

I know this isn't exactly what you're asking, but since you're trying to work with the HTML `<time>` element, your goal is to use a [machine readable format](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_time_datetime.asp), which I think you'll find general pointers going for this one.

Comment: I change the code, because i just need change that part of code. I tried both, the first one does not work, and the alternatively way print this: 2018-11-28T20:24:46+00:00 , thanks

Comment: If you got what you needed from my answer, please ✔ Accept the answer :)